# Why can't Logman start?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-xp, perfmon, logman

I'm setting up my first logman counter.  But it's not working!  There is some file or folder permissions problem. Or maybe I wrote the create-counter statement wrong.

Here's my counter commands:

```
logman create counter BillTest -si 30 -v nnnnnn -max 200 -o "C:\Temp" -c "\Processor(*)\*" "\Memory(*)\*" "\LogicalDisk(*)\*"
logman start BillTest
```

The first command works. It says counter creation successful.

The second command fails:

> Collection "BillTest" did not start,
>   check the application event log for
>   any errors

Here's the error in the Event Viewer:

> The service was unable to open the log
>   file C:\Temp_000001.blg for log
>   BillTest and will be stopped. Check
>   the log folder for existence,
>   spelling, permissions, and ensure that
>   no other logs or applications are
>   writing to this log file. You can
>   reenter the log file name using the
>   configuration program.   This log will
>   not be started. The error returned is:
>   Access is denied.

I verified that C:\Temp exists. I'm not a permissions guru, but I did set all the accounts in the security tab of that folder to "full control."  Still, the logman start command failed with the same error.

I noticed that it was trying to write to C:\Temp_000001.blg instead of C:\Temp\000001.blg. That might be part of the problem.  So, I tried to update my counter to "C:\Temp\" instead of "C:\Temp", but that failed with a path-invalid error.  Also, all the examples I saw online used did not put a trailing slash.  So, no dice there.

I tried this on my machine (Windows XP) and my dev server (Windows Server 2003).  Both failed with the same error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the -o to be:

`-o "c:\temp\mylogdata"`  It worked on my win 7 system after fixing that

Comment: That worked! Great! I would still like to understand why.  Got any idea?  I'm going to try to figure that out right now...

Comment: I suspect it's looking for a full file path when specified but it doesn't say that clearly in the /? text.  I'll have to take a look at it later myself.

Comment: 7 years after the answer was supplied: http://michaelsync.net/2014/05/07/performance-counters-errors . It seems there is a limitation for starting a capture where a .blg file already exists.